# How do you acquire the rewritten CFWheels URL of an given page?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

CFWheels has the [URLFor()](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/urlfor) function for getting the internal URL based on supplied arguments. Is there a way to get the internal URL without supplying any arguments?

For example: 
Given a user navigates to "http://somedomain.com" or "http://somedomain.com/about/" or "http://somedomain.com/contact/" is there a method like ReWrittenURL() that returns something like "/" or "/about/" or "/contact/"?

Using URLFor() with no arguments returns "/home/index" or "/about/index" or "/contact/index".

CGI.SCRIPT_NAME returns "/rewrite.cfm"

Obviously with Javascript using document.location.href I can get what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does CGI.path_info have the value you're looking for?

*edit*

At first, I deleted this post, being utterly confounded.  Now I've done a little test - I downloaded the latest wheels core files (1.1.6), extracted to an IIS 7.5 (with URL Rewrite module installed) + CF9 webserver, and edited the "web.config" file in the core root, setting "enabled='true'" for the rewrite rule.  Also, since I was running this example from a subfolder, I changed the path from "/rewrite.cfm" to just "rewrite.cfm".  This got me to the point where I was able to successfully requests urls like this:

http://server/wheelstest/wheels/wheels

From here, I edited the layout.cfm under views/wheels, adding:

```
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
```

When I then request the above URL (/wheelstest/wheels/wheels), I see the dump for the cgi scope.  Under path_info, this is the value: /wheels/wheels.

Next, I added a blank "index.cfm" file under views/wheels.

When I request /wheelstest/wheels, I get this for path_info: "/wheels".

When I request /wheelstest/wheels/, I get this for path_info: "/wheels/".

When I request /wheelstest/wheels/index, I get this for path_info: "/wheels/index".

When I request /wheelstest/wheels/index/, I get this for path_info: "/wheels/index/".

So basically - cgi.path_info is doing for me exactly what you describe you want.  What is different about your setup than mine, such that it isn't returning that value for you?

Comment: Nope. PATH_INFO returns "/rewrite.cfm"

Comment: That is very strange.  How about cgi.query_string?

Comment: Nope. cgi.query_string is empty.

Comment: `cgi.path_info` should get you what you're looking for. Sounds like there is something strange going on with your rewriting. May want to talk to the Google Group.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Sorry, my mistake! You are right. I must have been looking at a cgi dump from within a controller instead of a view or layout.cfm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

there might be a better way to do this... but here I go anyway

every page gets sent the #params#

```
    <cfdump var="#params#">
    <cfoutput>#params.action#/#params.controller#/#params.key#</cfoutput>
    <cfabort>
```

try putting that in a controller and see the results

the problem is that if the objects inside the `params` object don't exist you get an error. So the path that gets generated needs to check if the struct key exists and edit accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of the params object.

Comment: Actually, I take my previous comment back. Whilst this may work, you'd need to do checks if each variable exists. ALSO, the worst part is, it won't work for URL's with routes.

Answer (score 1):

CGI.Path_Info will give you the desired results. I've been trying different options however they all failed and went into the redirect loop. As soon as I switched CGI.path_info it all started well.